# NUCLEO-F411RE Openocd "Cannot identify target as a STM32 family."

Tags: rust, embedded, stm32, openocd, nucleo

- Nucleo with STM32F103RB
- STM32F3DISCOVERY
- Nucleo with STM32F411RE

I am currently trying to learn rust embedded thanks to 3 stm32 based developpement board :

I have no issue with the first two ones but I can not make work the F411RE with gdb & openocd. Everytime I try to flash (the same program that works fine with the two others) I receive this :

Openocd :
`

```
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.11.0
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
Info : auto-selecting first available session transport "hla_swd". To override use 'transport select <transport>'.
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
Info : clock speed 1000 kHz
Info : STLINK V2J33M25 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:374B
Info : Target voltage: 3.261538
Info : stm32f3x.cpu: hardware has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : starting gdb server for stm32f3x.cpu on 3333
Info : Listening on port 3333 for gdb connections
Info : accepting 'gdb' connection on tcp/3333
Info : device id = 0x10006431
Warn : Cannot identify target as a STM32 family.
Error: auto_probe failed
Error: Connect failed. Consider setting up a gdb-attach event for the target to prepare target for GDB connect, or use 'gdb_memory_map disable'.
Error: attempted 'gdb' connection rejected`
```

`
As you can see my board is detected but as soon as I try to connect to GDB, the board is not recognized.

Just so that you can check memory parameter :

`

```
FLASH : ORIGIN =   0x08000000, LENGTH = 512K
  RAM : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
```

`

I don't really know what to do knowing that it works very well on an other nucleo with an ARM cortex M3 and also with an other board but this time with an ARM cortex M4F.

Thank you for your help

Comment: `Info : stm32f3x.cpu` - suspicious line. Are you using F3 config files for F4?

Comment: Thank you. It was only that. Since I use a script that should handle openocd. I forgot to deal with STM32F4x !